# Chrome doesn't load liferay document without cache enabled

Tags: google-chrome, liferay, document

I have a image in my document library
Control Painel > Sites > MySite > Content > Document and Media

If I try to see the image, it is not rendered with success but in Network from Chrome Developer Tools I can see that it was retrieved with sucess with **code 200** (and cached). When I refresh the browser, it is retrieved as **302** and then it is presented correctly.
The same behavior happens when I try to load the image on my portal page.
I disabled Apache for debug and the same error happens, so I assume that is not a apache configuration problem.

The URL '`/documents/20182/0/88_MyImage.jpg/f1e771a6-930a-4381-8d52-4ba864f72005?t=1418941543978`' is the document that I'm trying to open and only works after a refresh.
However, if I use `/documents/20182/0/88_MyImage.jpg` instead, i.e., without the `/f1e771a6-930a-4381-8d52-4ba864f72005?t=1418941543978` it will always work.

I'm using JBoss EAP-6.2.0, Liferay 6.2.
The problem only happens in Chrome.

Comment: Any error logs triggered for this activity?

Comment: no, nothing. no errors on server side or browser console @shivam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a Chrome bug.
After reading the release notes of Chrome beta version 53, I notice that was a fix regarding images load when the connection is slow.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/560b2ab7f31013f1a0ad9f0c174cb1ccd267e132